# Appending big query results to existing table in java appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Basically i want to append query results from bigquery to an existing big query table without iterating over the results.
Bigquery results come in `List<TableRow>`.
Bigquery `insertAll()` requires a `TableDataInsertAllRequest` which has `.setRows()` method but this method only takes a  `List<TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows>` so i have to iterate over the `List<TableRow>` but since i am querying results with many rows this is inefficient.
So how do i configure a destination table in the query?

Comment: but you've received this results as a list, already. loaded into memory. I mean, what optimization you're looking for? it's not a stream

Comment: The optimization is that i do not even have to load the rows into memory by setting a destination table when querying bigquery. This is possible with asynchronous queries.

Comment: oh, I see. I just though you're looking for optimizations for table append

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google support gave me the answer. By just using an asynchronous query the destination table can be set as shown below.

```
JobConfigurationQuery queryConfig = new JobConfigurationQuery().setQuery(<querySql>);
queryConfig.setDestinationTable(<destination_table>);
queryConfig.setWriteDisposition("WRITE_APPEND");
Job job = new Job().setConfiguration(new JobConfiguration().setQuery(queryConfig));

bigquery.jobs().insert(projectId, job).execute();
```

Google support is awesome!

Comment: looks like it is exactly what is in my answer :o)

Comment: Yeah but this answer is especially for the bigquery java api wrapper ;)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [configuration.query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query) property of [Jobs: insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert) API

In particular - [configuration.query.writeDisposition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.writeDisposition) - specifies the action that occurs if the destination table already exists. In your case you should use  - WRITE_APPEND